# Simplest Python Multithreading - Writing a Simple File

Tags: python, multithreading

Really easy question...  I've been trying to implement multi-threading on some complex video processing (posted as a separate question!), but in the process of doing that think I've found an opportunity to implement additional multi-threading in other parts of my application.  It seems to work, but can't find many examples as simple as this and so wondering if it's doing what I think.  Code is as follows:

```
def update_safe_lock():
    with open('lock_file.txt', 'w') as f:
        print('%s' % timestamp(), file=f)

main():
    << other irrelevant code >>
    update_safe_lock()
    << other irrelevant code >>
```

Now I *think* can can just swap a single line in my `main()` function to make this file writing run in a separate thread, thereby allowing the rest of the code to run on without waiting for the file IO operation.  I've changed that line to:

```
Thread(target=update_safe_lock).start()
```

It doesn't throw any errors, and still writes the file, so I assume all is good.  But is it that simple?

If it really is this simple, then why isn't it more common practice?  For something so short, simple and easy to move basic non-critial file IO off the main thread, it seems like a no-brainer.

Thanks again :)

Comment: I never really used threading in python, but I imagine either the entire current state will be copied when creating new process or you don't get access to data you want to write, anyway improved performance is dubious, as you have to spend time creating process, making a copy of data etc when you could have cut down in other places. But then I might be wrong. Eh.

Comment: @IcedLance: multithreading should not create a new process (unless you are thinking of the Linux model).  One of the ideas of multithreading is to avoid creating a new process.  There *is* an overhead when creating a new thread, there's no free lunch, but it should be much less than creating a new process.  In python we have the GIL, that diminishes the usefulness of threading.

Comment: Is the timestamp the current time?  If so then is there much point in duplicating what the OS already provides?  Files on most file systems have a timestamp anyway, so you don't actually have to write anything to the file, just create it.  To retrieve it see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime

Comment: It is a common practice to use multiple threads in socket listening, file writing etc. But managing these threads and communicating between them should be implemented cautiously. In your case, are you starting the new thread an abandoning it? Or you're joining it back to main thread after sometime?

Comment: @SleebaPaul in this example I was literally just creating it for that one file write, and doing nothing with it after.  I assume when the file is written it's just terminated.  It's not time-critical, and doesn't matter if writes are missed, so should be no issues with race conditions, out-of-order execution or anything like that.  In this particular example, it's just creating a file which I'm using to ensure the application is still running - I've got cron trying to restart the script every few mins, but it'll only start if this file is old (indicating it's died / crashed).

Comment: @cdarke thanks for the observation, you're right I don't really need the timestamp in there, but figured I'd want to put something in the file and that seemed as good as anything.  As I just noted in my comment above, this specific example isn't important for the question, but for interest it's effectively implementing a pid-lock so I can ensure the process is still running (and restart it if it's died), but trying to maintain cross-platform compatibility which using the pid itself wouldn't allow.

Comment: @IcedLance, thanks I hadn't considered the overhead in creating a new thread.  Accepting it's less than multi-processing, for this particular example where I'm doing noting except writing a single tiny file that might explain why I'm not seeing much difference and actually might be slowing it down.  Good explanation!